# Meaning of 'merited'

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the adjective 'merited' in the below sentence?

> Gary's mistrust of his wife was merited.

None of the dictionary definitions of the verb 'merit' seem to fit here, and there is no definition of the adjective 'merited'.

Answer (score 5):

"Gary's mistrust of his wife was merited."

In this case:  merited = deserved

Merriam-Webster provides the following:

```
merit verb
merited; meriting; merits
Definition of merit (Entry 2 of 2)
transitive verb

: to be worthy of or entitled or liable to : EARN
intransitive verb

1: DESERVE
2obsolete : to be entitled to reward or honor
```

Could be re-written as one of the following:

- "Gary's mistrust of his wife was deserved." (she deserved his mistrust)
- "Gary's mistrust of his wife was earned." (she earned his mistrust through her actions)
- "Gary's mistrust of his wife was based on evidence"
- "Gary's mistrust of his wife was based on Gary's observation of her actions".